# How to convert a page of objects to list in spring data

Tags: java, spring-data

I have a page of objects like this:

```
Page<Video> videos = videoRepository.findAllVideos(new PageRequest(1, 50));
```

How can I convert that to a list of Video objs without iterating over my page?

Comment: found one solution using java stream. But it still is something where I would have to iterate: videos.forEach(videoList::add);

Comment: can someone explain why my question is not good rather than downvoting it?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please pay special attention to the sentence `Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague`. A good question is one that shows effort and research. Given that `Page` has a `getContent` method that returns a `List`, it does not seem that any research or effort was put in before asking the question. Hence, users (busy colleagues) are likely to be offended and therefore the downvotes.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
Page<Video> videos = videoRepository.findAllVideos(new PageRequest(1, 50));
List<Video> videosList = videos.getContent();
```

You can use the above code to get the list of videos from page

Comment: getContent() return just the single page's data. How to get everything from all pages?

Comment: Pagination used to get the records from the current page alone. If you want get all records from the Table you can use CrudRepository instead of PagingAndSortingRepository

Comment: Please note the current javadoc states that pages start at 0.

Answer (score 9):

Try this solution (and avoid all exception risks) :

```
Page<Video> videoPage = videoRepository.findAllVideos(new PageRequest(1, 50));
List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
if(videoPage != null && videoPage.hasContent()) {
    videoList = videoPage.getContent();
}
```